# Virtualbox Host is MacBook Pro Guest is Ubuntu 10.04 issues with github access

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, macbook, macbook-pro

Ok trying to do what I have done a dozen times over on dozens of PC's (literally). I am trying to access a private github account. Works no problem on any one of several computers all PC that I have setup around me with the same Virtualbox setup where the only 2 key differences are They are PC and they are Windows XP, Vista, 7. This is the only one thats a Mac. Although my co workers have Macbooks and are fine with this same setup, so I know this is an issue with a mac and the fact that I am fairly new to the world of mac.

So what I have, is a MacBook Pro 15" Late 2011 model. I have Mac OS X 10.7.2 as my Host machine, and Ubuntu 10.04 as my guest (and upgrading the guest os is not an option unfortunately).

I have set up my ssh keys for public/private, went to github to store them, went through the whole fun setting everything up.

Then comes the time to update the git information on the guest os. I go to do a git pull. And get denied. Scratching my head I went out and did a git -vT xxxx@xxxxxxx.com (obviously changed for public reasons here).. All seems to be working right, I think? But it gets to a point where it asks me for a password, and I try a number of different ones, from the accounts password on github to the private/public key password, keeps dening me. So.. any ideas? is there some step I am possibly missing or forgotten about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while since I visited this. However I found out the problem was my SSH Key was being stored and set up in the wrong location. When I discovered that I moved it, and all went smoothly from there.